# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable; occurs when calling class from another file

Tags: python, numpy

This is my first time posting on stackoverflow so thanks for the help. I am relatively new to python and this is my first time working on a personal project involving coding. The ultimate point of the file is to create a class to plot motor curves based on inputs. My main file currently is:

```
import motor
import plot

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        x = motor.motor(6.5,0.275,0.0343,1047,6)
        print(x.Imax,x.Imin,x.Tmax,x.Wmax,x.V,x.Kv(),x.Kt())    
        a = map(1047,0.0343,x.kt,0.275,6)
        #a.plot()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Quitting')
```

motor.py is working as expected. When the code gets to a = map(1047,0.343,x.kt,0.275,6) I get the error : TypeError :'float' object is not iterable. map is a class that I created and is provided by plot.py. The current code is as follows:

```
class map:
    def __init__(self,Wmax,Tmax,kt,Imin,V): 
        #Defines Inputs
        self.Wmax = Wmax
        self.Tmax = Tmax
        self.kt = kt
    self.Imin = Imin
        self.V = V

        #Defines motor opperating range
        self.Wrange = np.arange(0,int(self.Wmax),1) 

        #Defines Torque as a function of angular velocity
        #self.T_function = self.Tmax*(1-self.Wrange/self.Wmax)

        #Defines mechanical power as a functionof angular velocity
        #self.Pmech_function = self.Tmax*(1-self.Wrange/self.Wmax)\
        #*self.Wrange

        #Defines electrical power as a function of Torque
        #self.Pelec_function =((self.Tmax*(1-self.Wrange/self.Wmax\
        #))/self.kt+self.Imin)*self.V

        #Defines efficiency as a function of pmech and pelec
        #self.eff_function = (self.Tmax*(1-self.Wrange/self.Wmax)*\
        #self.Wrange)/(((self.Tmax*(1-self.Wrange/self.Wmax))/self\
        #.kt+self.Imin)*self.V) 

        #self.Wlabel = 'Angular Velocity (rad/sec)'
        #self.Tlabel = 'Torque (N-m)'
        #self.Pmech_label = 'Mechanical Power (Watts)'
        #self.Pelec_label = 'Electrical Power (Watts)'
        #self.eff_label ='Efficiency (%)'

""" def plot(self):
        #Creates main window
        fig = plt.figure()

        #Creates four y-axis
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax2 = ax.twinx()
        ax3 = ax.twinx()
        ax4 = ax.twinx()

        #Plots the above functions against Wrange
        ax.plot(self.Wrange,self.T_function,'-',color='black')
        ax1.plot(self.Wrange,self.Pmech_function,'-',color='red')
        ax2.plot(self.Wrange,self.Pelec_function,'-',color='blue')
        ax3.plot(self.Wrange,self.eff_function,'-',color='green')

        #Defines labels and grid
        ax4.grid(True)
        ax.set_xlabel(self.Wlabel)
        ax.set_ylabel(self.Tlabel)
        ax1.set_ylabel(self.Pmech_label)
        ax2.set_ylabel(self.Pelec_label)
        ax3.set_ylabel(self.eff_label)
        plt.show()
        """

test = map(1047,0.343,0.00551,0.275,6)
print(test.Wrange)
```

When I run plot.py as it's own file the two test lines on the end function as intended providing no errors. How can I resolve this error? Is there any advice for building a program like this?

Edit: I wasn't aware that map was a function from the standard library. I will be looking for this in the future. I will also be reducing the extra code in future posts. Thank you.

Comment: Please reduce this to just the code needed to demonstrate the problem. The vast majority of what you pasted here is either commented out or stuck in a string, so presumably it isn’t relevant. See [mcve] in the help, because it’s not at all obvious what does and doesn’t need to be in a question when you’re new to Stack Overflow, but the help tries to explain it.

Comment: Also, please give us the full exception, not just a description of it. Even if all that stuff means nothing to you, its usually very useful to the people trying to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't call your class "map".  That's a function name in the standard library, so things are going to get confused.  Your call `a = map(1047,0.343,x.kt,0.275,6)` is getting the standard library one, which is why the error message is weird and confusing.  If you rename the class, things will make more sense.

By convention, your class names should start with an uppercase letter (partially to avoid this kind of confusion).